# Connecting Facebook with Flask-Social

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flask

I'm very confused when I'm trying to connect FB to my App.
So, in config.py I have:

```
FB_APP_ID='xxx'
FB_APP_SECRET='xxx'
FB_APP_NAME='xxx'
```

I need only a simple button that says "Log in with Facebook" in a template (no idea how to put it) and that, we you click on it, your name, your e-mail and your profile photo are shown in another template, and I've been reading a lot but I don't understand.
Could you help me please? :/ :(

Comment: you tyipically need to make 3 calls for this ... 1. redirect to facebook oath login endpoint with appid and appname perhaps and a redirect_uri ,,, after they login on facebook facebook redirects back to your `redirect_uri` with a token value attached to the get parameters ... you then `post` a request to the token exchange endpoint with your secret and the temporary token), facebook hands you back a json dictionary that may have all the info you want in it ... if not you might need to call the userinfo endpoint

Comment: Joran's answer is a great starting point for you; it explains on a high level the steps involved in building a script/an app like the one you are describing. If you are looking for more details on how the Facebook OAuth 2.0 login works, you can check out Facebook's "[Manually building a login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2)" documentation. The "[Using the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2)" document explains how to make graph API queries in general.